# Does the Mukai's lemma hold for non-algebraic $K3$ surfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, k3-surfaces

In Huybrechts' book *Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry* I found the following result due to Mukai (Page 232, Lemma 10.6)

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $K3$ surfaces. Then the Mukai vector of any object $\mathcal{E}^{\bullet}\in D^b(X\times Y)$ is an integral cohomology class $v(\mathcal{E}^{\bullet})\in H^*(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})$.*

I want to ask if this result is for any $K3$ surfaces or just algebraic $K3$ surfaces. I am asking because the proof uses the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem (Page 127, Theorem 5.26), which holds for the algebraic case only.

Moreover, I am not sure if $X\times Y$ has the resolution property. If not, then it is not even easy to define the Chern character of a general object $\mathcal{E}^{\bullet}\in D^b(X\times Y)$.

Comment: Please confer O’Brian — Toledo — Tong.